# Show that it is false that every factor group of a nonabelian group is nonabelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that it is false that every factor group of a nonabelian group is nonabelian.

I found this question while studying Fraleigh's algebra book, section 14, exercise 23, a true or false exercise. What is wrong with my thought:

There exist $g_1$ and $g_2$ of a nonabelian group G such that $g_1Hg_2H=g_1g_2H\neq g_2g_1H=g_2Hg_1H$. So there exist $g_1Hg_2H\neq g_2Hg_1H$.

Comment: The trivial group is always a quotient group.  Work through your logic in that case (i.e. $H=G$)

Comment: There are plenty of easy non-Abelian groups having a factor group of size two.

Comment: How do you establish that $g_1g_2H\neq g_2h_1H$? You would need to show not just that $g_1g_2\neq g_2g_1$, but also that $(g_1g_2)^{-1}(g_1g_2)\notin H$.

Comment: Yes, your comments already answer my question. The passage $g_1g_2H\neq g_2h_1H$ is wrong and there is the trivial group counter-example. Thank you all.